# How to work with libddx and Android studio

Tags: libgdx

I am new in game development.I am getting problem with libgdx. when i download libgdx i get zip file.where is setup[image: This is setup file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [setting up your development environment](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans)) (process varies depending on what you plan to use), you can [use the Libgdx wizard tool](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) 
 (gdx-setup.jar) to create a Gradle ready project, which can then be imported into your IDE:

1. Download LibGDX Project setup tool "gdx-setup.jar"
2. Open your command line tool, go to the download folder and run:
   `java -jar ./gdx-setup.jar`